# Django uploading large files: takes time to reach till the first line of view

Tags: django

I have simple view which get a file

```
def upload_file(request):
     print("first line")
     ....
```

Here when i upload a file of 800 MB, the printing of `first line` itself takes 5-10 sec or more

Definitely I am expecting it to take time, when i try to access it like `upload_file = request.data['file']` because it has to create a copy of the file in /tmp. But here even before that it takes lot of time.

I hope its taking time to build the request object itself.

Or is it time time taken from the browser to the django

I just wanted to know whats taking the time

Also i checked the docker container stats and following are my observations.

[image]

The following is my middlewares in settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",

]
```

How to avoid this delay is to uploading the file.

I also tried with a custom middleware and added it to the first

```
def testing(get_response):
    # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def middleware(request):
        print("**********INSIDE MIDDLEWARE***************")

        response = get_response(request)

        # Code to be executed for each request/response after
        # the view is called.

        return response

    return middleware
```

When the file size is large the print statement get executed after a long time.

Comment: `upload_file` defined by you, `request` building also depends on your code. This question is not answerable. Use debug and stop points to track your request.

Comment: `request building also depends on your code`: How come ? My code starts only after we get the request object.

Comment: added my answer-comment as answer, because it big to be just a comment

Answer (score 0):

> My code starts only after we get the request object

That is not correct (at least correct just at half).
You should understand `request` [flow](https://data-flair.training/blogs/django-request-response-cycle/)

This is a pretty good picture ([original URL](https://medium.com/@ksarthak4ever/django-request-response-cycle-2626e9e8606e)):

[image: request flow]

Your `upload_file` beholds at bottom of the picture (`View`). Just in middle of the flow.

Here is not information about what Middleware you using (even if that is not your code). Did you have own Middlewares? Did you override `View` classes? etc.

But according information that you added, we can guess that file stream request should be finalized before Middlewares will be able to handle and inspect it. By some logic Django decide that stream request data is big and can't be stored at memory.

So possible data flow will be (Just my unchecked guess):

1. Handle `request` by first Middleware
2. Store stream request data to `/tmp` directory
3. Handle `request` by other Middlewares
4. Handle `request` by some pre-processing View methods (if it exists)
5. Handle `request` by your `upload_file` function
6. Copy file from `/tmp` to permanent directory and rename it
7. Remove temporary file (or remove it after ⑧'s response)
8. Send `response` to Middlewares again

So here is hard to guess what exactly happens in your code (or inside all third-party libraries and Middlewares that you use).

If you want to handle stream request object immediately add own Middleware as `settings.MIDDLEWARE`'s first element.

Comment: I didnt use any special middlewares or override view classes. I have added the middlewares in the edited question

Comment: @Santhosh and you expecting that someone will check code of these 8 Middlewares and provide a completed answer? As I answered above you have two ways to solve the problem: ① create own Middleware and put in `MIDDLEWARE` list as first element. This Middleware class will receive `request` at first. ② Remove all Middlewares from `MIDDLEWARE` list and handle every raw request manually inside View class.

Comment: I will check that.

Comment: I tried that also, the request object still takes time. edited my question